# Errors using Visual Studio XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe) Schema Validation Warning

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an xml file that I am trying to create a class file from using the XSD.exe tool in Visual Studio. Here is the XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
<PayloadManifest xmlns="http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport">
<manifest contentID="Content0" namespaceURI="?" element="?" relatedID="?" version="?" /> 
</PayloadManifest>
<wsa:Action>http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport/operations/ProcessMessageResponse</wsa:Action> 
<wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:b56c3b11-d4a7-4372-9e6a-7498aa2aeb06</wsa:MessageID> 
<wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:71089910-41d4-4104-bbd7-2b3ac7cece0f</wsa:RelatesTo> 
<wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To> 
<wsse:Security>
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-abc8d6ea-d75d-42a2-b042-87309692c2bb">
<wsu:Created>2012-06-27T19:14:43Z</wsu:Created> 
<wsu:Expires>2012-06-27T19:19:43Z</wsu:Expires> 
</wsu:Timestamp>
</wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<ProcessMessageResponse xmlns="http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport">
<payload>
<content id="Content0">
<VehicleSaleGroupsTable xmlns="">
<VehicleSaleGroupRecord xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CompanyNumber>ZE7</CompanyNumber> 
<FranchiseType>N</FranchiseType> 
<FranchiseCode>NC</FranchiseCode> 
<FranchiseDescription>NEW CAR</FranchiseDescription> 
<Manufacturer /> 
<UsedSaleAccount /> 
<UsedInventoryAccount /> 
</VehicleSaleGroupRecord>
<VehicleSaleGroupRecord xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CompanyNumber>ZE7</CompanyNumber> 
<FranchiseType>N</FranchiseType> 
<FranchiseCode>NT</FranchiseCode> 
<FranchiseDescription>NEW TRUCK</FranchiseDescription> 
<Manufacturer /> 
<UsedSaleAccount /> 
<UsedInventoryAccount /> 
</VehicleSaleGroupRecord>
<VehicleSaleGroupRecord xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CompanyNumber>ZE7</CompanyNumber> 
<FranchiseType>U</FranchiseType> 
<FranchiseCode>UC</FranchiseCode> 
<FranchiseDescription>USED CAR</FranchiseDescription> 
<Manufacturer /> 
<UsedSaleAccount>USALE</UsedSaleAccount> 
<UsedInventoryAccount>UINV</UsedInventoryAccount> 
</VehicleSaleGroupRecord>
<VehicleSaleGroupRecord xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CompanyNumber>ZE7</CompanyNumber> 
<FranchiseType>U</FranchiseType> 
<FranchiseCode>UT</FranchiseCode> 
<FranchiseDescription>USED TRUCK</FranchiseDescription> 
<Manufacturer /> 
<UsedSaleAccount>USALE</UsedSaleAccount> 
<UsedInventoryAccount>UINV</UsedInventoryAccount> 
</VehicleSaleGroupRecord>
</VehicleSaleGroupsTable>
</content>
</payload>
</ProcessMessageResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I opened the Visual Studio command line program and typed the following:

> C:\xml2xsd\xsd myXML.xml

It generated 5 xsd files and then I typed the following:

> C:\xml2xsd\xsd /c myXML.xsd

and I got the following message with no class files created:

> Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
>   [Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.3038]
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>   Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport:ProcessMessageResponse' element is not declared. Line 25, position 16.
>   Schema validation warning: The 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing:Action' element is not declared. Line 13, position 16.
>   Schema validation warning: The 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing:MessageID' element is not declared. Line 14, position 16.
>   Schema validation warning: The 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing:RelatesTo' element is not declared. Line 15, position 16.
>   Schema validation warning: The 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing:To' element is not declared. Line 16, position 16.
>   Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport:PayloadManifest' element is not declared. Line 17, position
>    16.
>   Schema validation warning: The 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd:Security' element is not declared. L
>   ine 18, position 16.
>
> Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce incorrect results.
>
> Error: Error generating classes for schema 'myxmlRESfile'.
>     - The element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing:Action' is missing.
>
> If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".

Any help would be appreciated in getting these class files generated.  I have never used this tool before.

THanks!